# Looking for a HTML to PDF builder with CSS and large table support for a PHP based Webinterface

Tags: php, html, pdf, css-tables

We want to save a dynamically generated html page (which consists of a large CSS styled table, which would probably cover more than one page) into a pdf.

We tried the following classes and tools (fpdf,html2p,dompdf) - but nothing worked. It has to run on Windows.

Any other tools with references to a doku or examples would be very appreciated!

Comment: This could of some use: http://ted.mielczarek.org/hg/moz-headless-screenshot/file/tip/Makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing you might try is [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/). I've used it myself for the same purpose, although the output in PDF varies as its still under development.

PNG support is fantastic though.

Comment: phantomJS looks promising as a *full-featured* headless webkit browser.  Very interesting.

Comment: so with code evaluation and "document.getElementById('mydiv').render(output);" i should have my div rendered as a pdf ?

Comment: is it somehow possible to config phantom to render the pdf in landscape format as i have a broad table with many columns ?

Comment: @Gamer, some of the examples do exactly what you ask. This is a cmd-line tool, so you just have to run the following: "phantomjs rasterize.js http://mysite.com mysite.pdf". Look at the rasterize.js file to see how they are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

We recently implemented [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).  It uses a headless webkit renderer, so the layout is pretty darned true to what you see in Chrome/Safari, etc., including modern CSS, JS and even SVG.  It's cross-platform.  And happiness inducing.

Comment: is it possible to render the content of a specific DIV (in this case where the table is located) to a pdf ?

Comment: Gamer, that is possible using PhantomJS. See the Code Evaluation and DOM Manipulation sections at this link for some starting points: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart

Comment: wkhtmltopdf works at the page level, so you would need to spit out a special page with just what you want.  I'd say you'd best go with phantomJS if you prefer to not monkey with pages.